# Difference between using prefix "ansible.builtin" and without

Tags: ansible

In tutorials I find sometimes:

```yaml
- name: Copy something
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "src/foo"
    dest: "dest/foo"
```

but sometimes:

```yaml
- name: Copy something
  copy:
    src: "src/foo"
    dest: "dest/foo"
```

What is the difference to using the prefix `ansible.builtin`?

Comment: It defines a module under a [Collection in the Ansible Namespace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/index.html) more specifically. This was only introduced at a later date, that's why you'll find in older docs and tutorials the short naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form `ansible.builtin.copy` is what Ansible calls the [*fully-qualified collection name (FQCN)*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Fully-Qualified-Collection-Name-FQCN) of the module, and it is advisable to actually always use it.

Before [Ansible 2.10, where the FQCN were generalized](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.10.html#ansible-2-10-porting-guide), you would not be able to have two modules named `copy`, forcing for long modules names, i.e. `copy` versus `postgresql_copy`, which might be cumbersome in some cases.

Since 2.10, Ansible stopped maintaining the modules of third parties in its own codebase and those modules are, now, grouped in [collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections_guide/index.html)  and installable via the mean of [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/).

So, now, you could have, in your installed collections, a module `ansible.builtin.copy` and a module `community.postgresql.copy`, although, in this case and for backward compatibility, the module is still named `community.postgresql.postgresql_copy`.

While Ansible is able to resolve the collection of a module if it is not fully qualified — explaining why using `copy` is working too, specifying the FQCN will ensure that you are using the module you really intended to.

---

Further reading:

- [Ansible lint FQCN usage rule](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/fqcn/)
- [Frequently asked questions: Where did all the modules go?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#where-did-all-the-modules-go)
- [General tips: Use fully qualified collection names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/tips_tricks/ansible_tips_tricks.html#use-fully-qualified-collection-names)